# How to determine what packages are being scanned with spring logging

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I'm trying to figure out why my @Autowire isn't autowiring my service.  I'd like to verify the proper packages are being scanned.

I've implemented log4j in my application and an using the config:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

I see some lines...

```
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'unit'
12:45:19,627 DEBUG main packaging.AbstractJarVisitor:172 - Filtering: com.production.api.dao.Config
12:45:19,628 DEBUG main packaging.AbstractJarVisitor:172 - Filtering: com.production.api.dao.GenericDao
12:45:19,642 DEBUG main packaging.AbstractJarVisitor:172 - Filtering: com.production.api.dao.JobAssetDao
12:45:19,643 DEBUG main packaging.AbstractJarVisitor:172 - Filtering: com.production.api.dao.JobDao
12:45:19,644 DEBUG main packaging.AbstractJarVisitor:172 - Filtering: com.production.api.dao.JobSetDao
```

Do these lines indicate that those packages are being scanned?  `Filtering` to me sounds like it's being filtered out, not scanned.

**Update:** I have another question posted here: [How to fix xml-less autowiring of service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009641/how-to-fix-xml-less-autowiring-of-service) on resolving my autowire issue.  But I was hoping to keep this question focused on the logging of spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was disappointed that no one was able to answer this.  Apparently the below line will tell you what classes are being loaded as beans...

```
Feb 28, 2013 1:16:11 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3ff33ecb: defining beans ....
```

Answer (score 1):

That logging looks like Hibernate, not Spring. Your conversion pattern is not helping; I suggest you drop the `{2}` after `%c`, to show the full logger package name.

Comment: You're right, it's all hibernate.  How I have spring set to DEBUG, why can't I see any spring output?

Comment: We'd need to see more of your application's configuration. Is other Spring autowiring working?

Answer (score 0):

Well I started using Spring Stool suite for Spring development and I feature is that if a class is defined as bean using annotation you would see a arrow and a symbol "S" on the file name in Project explorer.

Second approach would be remove annotation on that particular class/method only and  define in your context.xml class. Probably the package name is incorrect.