# How to fix xml-less autowiring of service

Tags: spring, jersey, grizzly

When I call a service directly in my `main()` I can query the database and things work fine.  When a jersey request comes in and maps the JSON to `NewJobRequest` I can't use my service because the `@Autowire` failed.

**My app:**

```
public class Main {

    public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
    }

    protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.production.api.resources");
        rc.getFeatures()
            .put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);

        return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        //if this is uncommented, it'll successfully query the database
        //VendorService vendorService = (VendorService)ctx.getBean("vendorService");
        //Vendor vendor = vendorService.findByUUID("asdf"); 

        HttpServer httpServer = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at " + "%sapplication.wadl\nTry out %shelloworld\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI, BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        httpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

**My Resource (controller):**

```
@Component
@Path("/job")
public class JobResource extends GenericResource {
    @Path("/new")
    @POST
    public String New(NewJobRequest request) {
        return "done";
    }
}
```

**Jersey is mapping the JSON post to:**

```
@Component
public class NewJobRequest {

    @Autowired
    private VendorService vendorService;

    @JsonCreator
    public NewJobRequest(Map<String, Object> request) {
        //uh oh, can't do anything here because @Autowired failed and vendorService is null
    }
}
```

**VendorService:**

```
@Service
public class VendorService extends GenericService<VendorDao> {

    public Vendor findByUUID(String uuid) {
        Vendor entity = null;
        try {
            return (Vendor)em.createNamedQuery("Vendor.findByUUID")
                    .setParameter("UUID", uuid)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
@Service
public class GenericService<T extends GenericDao> {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit")
    public EntityManager em;

    protected T dao;

    @Transactional
    public void save(T entity) {
        dao.save(entity);
    }
}
```

**My service config:**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public VendorService vendorService() {
        return new VendorService();
    }
}
```

**My config**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production.api",
        "com.production.api.dao",
        "com.production.api.models",
        "com.production.api.requests",
        "com.production.api.requests.job",
        "com.production.api.resources",
        "com.production.api.services"
})
@Import({
        com.production.api.services.Config.class,
        com.production.api.dao.Config.class,
        com.production.api.requests.Config.class
})
@PropertySource(value= "classpath:/META-INF/application.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USER = "db.user";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USER));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("unit");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you have a lot of `Config` classes.  Are you sure you are passing the correct one into the `ApplicationContext` you are creating in `main()`?

Comment: Where is it configuring the Jersey front controller servlet?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild - Good question.  I've confirmed that it is because they're the only 2 classes in the base package.

Comment: @LeeMeador - I'll update the above post with the rest of my `Main` class to show where it's being initialized.

Comment: I'm wondering who creates the instance of NewJobRequest that Jersey is calling and how it would get values injected and how Jersey would know about it. The instance Jersey knows about may not be the one Spring is creating.

Comment: @LeeMeador That's a great point... I'll try some Googling on that note.

Comment: Normally the Jersey servlet would be configured in web.xml but I don't know how Grizzley does it.

Comment: `} catch (Exception ex) { return null;` ... Please don't ever do this. Swallowing the stack trace makes debugging really hard

Comment: @artbristol - Good catch, I modified it so as to log as Level.WARNING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the issue and blogged about it here: http://blog.benkuhl.com/2013/02/how-to-access-a-service-layer-on-a-jersey-json-object/

In the mean time, I'm also going to post the solution here:

I need to tap into the bean that Spring already created so I used Spring's [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

And then used that static context reference within my object to be mapped to so I can perform lookups in the service:

```
public class NewJobRequest {

    private VendorService vendorService;

    public NewJobRequest() {
        vendorService = (VendorService) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("vendorService");
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public NewJobRequest(Map<String, Object> request) {
        setVendor(vendorService.findById(request.get("vendorId")); //vendorService is null
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I would take a look here http://javaswamy.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/making-jersey-work-with-spring.html if I were you. Although accessing the Spring application context statically does work, it goes against the spirit of DI.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Path` and `@POST` annotations are JAX-RS, not Spring. So the container is instantiating your endpoints on its own, without any knowledge of Spring beans. You are most likely not getting any Spring logging because Spring is not being used at all.